# IE10 : createDocumentFragment null reference or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using jquery 1.9.1, bootstrap 3, font awesome, jquery-mobile (for touch event)
It works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE10 I get a blank screen when submitting an AJAX form:

Error (translated from French):

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property «
>   createDocumentFragment » NULL reference or undefined 
>   jquery.min.js, Line 4 char 23990

```
<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" data-load="main"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" data-load="main"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-load="main"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history.js/1.8/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.min.js" type="text/javascript" data-load="main"></script>  
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" data-load="main"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" data-load="once" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52dd220911b01466"></script>
```

Comment: This is the line that is causing the error, in the original jQuery 1.9.1 source code (for easier reading): https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/manipulation.js#L3